# Error in using "for /R " loop in on dos command line for directory with spaces between words such as "Documents and Settings"

Tags: for-loop, syntax, command, windows-xp, dos

I am thinking of using robocopy.exe to back up my photos from variouse devices synchronized to "C:\documents and settings" under different folders, and my command line syntax is as follows:

for /r c:\documents and settings %g in (.) do c:\robocopy %g c:\photos *.jpg /xo

This syntax is aiming at copying all .jpg files in sub folders of c:\documents and settings to the c:\photos so that I can browse thumnails without having to change folders, and also to avoid copying of files with identical date and time mark to c:\photos to save time.

The error was that the loop will parse the "documents and settings" to individual words and look for files under C:\documents, c:\documents\and hence resulting in errors.

I have tried to put quotes around "Documents and Setting" and also "\documents and settings" but without success.

It worked perfectly well with directories without any spaces in the folder name like below but failed when presented above :

for /r c:\abc %g in (.) do c:\robocopy %g c:\photos *.jpg /xo

when there are jpg files in folders c:\abc\galaxy  and c:\abc\iphone.

Is there any way that I can improve this syntax to achieve what I wanted?

Thanks and regards
Marco Wong

Comment: Did you try putting quotes around "Documents and Settings"?

Comment: Yes, also tried c:"\documents and settings" suggested by some websites.

Answer (score 0):

You did not put quotes around the parameter to robocopy, so its first param ended up being wrong. For paths with NO spaces, this wouldn't matter, so that's why it worked.

BAD CODE:
for /r c:\documents and settings %g in (.) do c:\robocopy %g c:\photos *.jpg /xo

CORRECTED CODE:

```
for /r "c:\documents and settings" %g in (.) do c:\robocopy "%g" c:\photos *.jpg /xo
```

(notice quotes on robocopy "%g" too.. not just the docs and settings for the recursive FOR)